# Excel VBA: Designate Variable as Folderspec

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having trouble with this, hopefully minor issue and I cant seem to figure out how to solve it.

I have a vba script that works well in merging multiple workbook/worksheets into 1. However, the path of the folder is a static path. I'd like to make it a variable that can be defined by a filedialog function.

Here is the existing code for the file merger:

```
Sub ProjectMerger()
Dim bookList As Workbook
Dim mergeObj As Object, dirObj As Object, filesObj As Object, everyObj As Object
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set mergeObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'change folder path of excel files here
Set dirObj = mergeObj.GetFolder("C:\Users\testUser\Desktop\FolderTest")
Set filesObj = dirObj.Files
For Each everyObj In filesObj
Set bookList = Workbooks.Open(everyObj)
```

Here is the script to use filedialog:

```
Function GetFolder() As String
    Dim fldr As FileDialog
    Dim sItem As String
    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With fldr
        .Title = "Select a Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
NextCode:
    GetFolder = sItem
    Set fldr = Nothing
End Function
```

I would think it would be easy enough to replace the folder path string with sItem to get this to work, but doing so always results in errors. Do i have to designate sItem as something else in order use it as the path? I'm not very familiar how Functions work vs regular subs.

Comment: *doing so always results in errors* - what errors? Which instruction is throwing it? If you're unfamiliar with an API, it would be better to use early-binding than late-binding and work blindly against an `Object`; add a reference to the *Microsoft Scripting Runtime* library, and declare your FSO `As Scripting.FileSystemObject`, and use the *object browser* (F2) to see what types are available for you to use in that library, and what their members are. There is no reason whatsoever to late-bind the scripting runtime if your code isn't going to run on Windows XP or earlier.

Comment: A `Sub` *does something*, a `Function` *returns a value* - you're doing great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to capture the selected path returned from the function & deal with the possibility of it being empty if the user cancelled the dialog, E.g.

```
Dim path As String
path = GetFolder()

If (path <> "") Then
    Set dirObj = mergeObj.GetFolder(path)
    ....
    ....
Else
    '// user cancelled
End If
```

Comment: Upvoted, but note that parentheses in `path = GetFolder()` and `If (path <> "") Then` are redundant and can be removed. I would also advise to use the `vbNullString` built-in constant instead of an `""` empty string literal, for the same reasons .NET code perfers `string.Empty` over `""` for that purpose.

Comment: Great thank you all! Just wanted to mention, I have the function separate from the merge sub and simply am calling the function. That wouldn't cause any further complications correct?

Comment: @piccolomair I've no idea what that sentence means, but hey if it works, it works.